# Has the EOS ICO dumped all of their Ethereum it raised during the year long ICO?

Tags: ico, block.one

EOS raised 4 billion worth of Ether in the long 1 year ICO. Has the EOS team dumped all of their ether already? What were the addresses of the ICO funds and where did they dump it?

Answer (score 2):

The Ethereums that Block.one earned from ICO is literally converted into real cash.
 They sold it back to really money because that's the whole point of doing ICO, earning funds for further development.

Comment: Where was this stated? Any sources?